# What does "Return false;" in onclick event for JavaScript mean?

Tags: javascript

What does "Return false;" in onclick event for JavaScript mean?

```
    <input 
      type="button" 
      runat="server" 
      id="btnCancel" 
      value=" Cancel " 
      style="width:70px;"
      onclick="document.location.href = 'ReportPanel.aspx'; return false;" 
    />
```

in the onclick event. It has `return false;` What does it mean? What does it mean if `return true;`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It says "the event never happened" to the browser. If you had a submit button instead of a simple button and didn't have "return false", the form would get submitted when you click it (after executing the javascript).

Comment: Right - without it the click would still be processed and the browser will navigate away or perform the form submit action.

Comment: It is the same as to set the server control properties as  PostbackEnabled="false" in asp.net  ,right?

Comment: Actually, no ;-) Enabling postback on the server side introduces specific javascript code to your html. So, your simple HTML select becomes  <select onchange="callPostback()"> where the callPostback() explicitly submits the form back to itself.